# Compare the MSE between LASSO and OLS

Tags: lasso, ridge-regression

In regression, the MSE of estimation $\hat{\theta}$ is:

$$MSE = E[(\hat{\theta} - \theta)^2].$$

I know the detailed comparison of MSE between OLS and Ridge. But can hardly find some materials between LASSO and  OLS/Ridge. One reason I guess is that LASSO has no closed form of estimation. However at least, I want to know is
$$MSE_{LASSO}(\lambda)\leq MSE_{OLS}$$
true for any $\lambda?$

Could you refer some materials for this topic?